# How do I get a reference to the polygon clicked? (google maps api v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've set up some polygons, drew them on the map just fine. I also managed to fire console.log when they were clicked. However, how would I go on about figuring out which polygon was actually clicked?

As you can see in my sample code here I store each object within the collection "lots", however - clicking them only gives me the lat-long of the click. I figured I might need to loop through my polygons and check if the point was clicked is intersecting them and thus figure out which polygon it is... is there an easier solution?

```
var lot = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: me.area,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeOpacity: 0.35,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: fillcol,
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});

lot.setMap(map);
var obj = {
    'id':me.id,
    'rented':me.rented,
    'area':lot
};

google.maps.event.addListener(lot, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});

lots.push(lot);
```

Comment: Turned out getPath() works like a charm.
I did not realize I actually got the polygon reference passed on the click event, to match this with my stored "lots" I simply loop through my stored lots and compare this.getPath to other.getPath, if they match I know which lot was clicked and can now show info related to this particular object.

Comment: You may have to wait a few hours before the site will let you do so, but you should post this as an answer if you can.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't assign to each polygon some id property when you create them and later just use **this.myID**? Truly speaking, you can hang all information you need on that polygon object.

```
var lot = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: me.area,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeOpacity: 0.35,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: fillcol,
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    lot.setMap(map);

    var obj = {
        'id':me.id,
        'rented':me.rented,
        'area':lot
    };
    lot.objInfo = obj;

    google.maps.event.addListener(lot, 'click', function(event) {
        console.log(this.objInfo);
    });

    lots.push(lot);
```

It would be more effective than path comparison in a loop, or am i missing something? :)

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure, thing is I never really thought of adding my own properties to the polygon object but I guess that's smoother then comparing the path yes =)

Comment: @Bisa And as of javascript stores references to objects and arrays, not copys, memory consumption in this case stays the same.

Comment: right, thats a solid argument, In my original solution I'd copy the values and compare them rather then compare references - I'll rewrite my code a bit ^^ thnx

Comment: with a little correction, instead of refering to lot.objInfo in the event function I had to use this.objInfo - a much cleaner (not to mention faster) solution, changed this answer as the correct answer to my question.

Answer (score 8):

If I can step in a little late with a different solution, I was having the same problem and discovered that you can define custom properties on a polygon.

My example (which creates a state on a map of the U.S.)

```
poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map_state_id: map_state_id,
    paths: pts,
    fillColor: colour,
    fillOpacity: 0.66,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    clickable:true
    });
```

In this case "map_state_id" is the custom property. I have defined it to be the ID of the state (1 for Alabama, 2 for Alaska, etc.)

Then when the particular state is clicked later, this "map_state_id" can be passed into the event function.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function() 
    {
    var map_state_id = this.map_state_id; //retrieve correct state_id

    $.ajax(
        {
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www...get_state_info.php",
        data: {state_id : map_state_id},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data)
            {
            $("#state_info").html(data); //display some info
            }                       
        });
    });
```

I found this particular concept at http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-your-own-property-field-to-google.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out using the 'this.' -- that was needed to disambiguate the polys.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out getPath() works like a charm. I did not realize I actually got the polygon reference passed on the click event, to match this with my stored "lots" I simply loop through my stored lots and compare this.getPath to other.getPath, if they match I know which lot was clicked and can now show info related to this particular object.

Here's a code sample:
(where parking is an array of my parking area objects which themselves have arrays containing parking lot objects)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(lot, 'click', function(event) {

     var myPath = this.getPath();

          for(var i = 0; i < parking.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < parking[i].lots.length; j++){
                var lot = parking[i].lots[j];

                var otherPath = lot.poly.getPath();

                if(otherPath == myPath){
                    console.log(lot);
                    break;
                }
            }
          }

        });
```

Comment: as per Trotts suggestion I've posted my comment above as an answer as well as providing some sample code - won't let me mark this as my answer until tomorrow tho ;)