# Multiple polygons in Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, resize, polygon

Is there any way to id multiple polygons in Google maps v3? 
Also, can you track when a polygon changes size? I wasn't clear about how to do that from the Google Maps API guide.

I want to set up a div or textbox that has the size of a polygon on creation, but changes value when the user changes the size.

Comment: [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_wolfpil_de_flexible-polygon.html) that computes the area of an editable polygon on the fly.  Credit to [Wolfgang Pichler](http://www.wolfpil.de/index.html).  You can now do the same with [editable Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#editable).

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581815/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-polygon-clicked-google-maps-api-v3) answer was also helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just defined my own `id` property, and used that - pretty simple, actually